# ReplaceWith Conditional DTE

Tags: regex, vb.net, if-statement, envdte, replacewith

I want to match the terms "**TextCtrls**" and "**LabelCtrls**".
When I find "TextCtrls" I want to replace with "**Txt**" and when I find "LabelControls" I want to replace with "**Lbl**". [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/We97pa/92)

**Is this possible with DTE.Find.ReplaceWith?**

```
DTE.Find.FindWhat = "Container\(""\w+""\)\.(?:TextCtrls|LabelCtrls)\(""(?<ControlName>\w+)""\).Text"

DTE.Find.ReplaceWith = "<psydocode:Txt|Lbl>${ControlName}.Text"
```

Comment: Your demo is not quite clear. Please explain what output you expect for both the sample strings.

Comment: I expect: 
TxtNameOfControl.Text when it was TextCtrls and
LblNameOfControl.Text when it was LabelCtrls

Comment: Do you have actual access to VB.NET code?

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help, and if not please consider accepting the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1: Reusing the text present in input string

Since the text you want to replace with actually is present in the source text, you may (ab)?use the capturing groups here the following way:

```
DTE.Find.FindWhat = "Container\(""\w+""\)\.(?:(?<f>T)e(?<s>xt)Ctrls|(?<f>L)a(?<s>b)e(?<t>l)Ctrls)\(""(?<ControlName>\w+)""\).Text"
DTE.Find.ReplaceWith = "${f}${s}${t}NameOfControl.Text"
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Container%5c%28%22%5cw%2b%22%5c%29%5c.%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cf%3eT%29e%28%3f%3cs%3ext%29Ctrls%7c%28%3f%3cf%3eL%29a%28%3f%3cs%3eb%29e%28%3f%3ct%3el%29Ctrls%29%5c%28%22%28%3f%3cControlName%3e%5cw%2b%29%22%5c%29.Text&i=Container%28%22Name1%22%29.TextCtrls%28%22Name2%22%29.Text%0d%0aContainer%28%22Name1%22%29.LabelCtrls%28%22Name2%22%29.Text&r=%24%7bf%7d%24%7bs%7d%24%7bt%7dNameOfControl.Text)

Groups `f`, `s` and `t` are filled with the necessary bits of text and only have text if the corresponding alternatives match.

[image]

## Solution 2: Using `MatchEvaluator` for custom replacement logic

You may use [`MatchEvaluator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator?view=netframework-4.7.2) to check what group matched or what group value is and then implement your own replacement logic:

```
Dim s As String = "Container(""Name1"").TextCtrls(""Name2"").Text" & vbCrLf & "Container(""Name1"").LabelCtrls(""Name2"").Text"
Dim pattern As String = "Container\(""\w+""\)\.(?<test>TextCtrls|LabelCtrls)\(""(?<ControlName>\w+)""\).Text"
Dim result = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, New MatchEvaluator(Function(m As Match)
        If m.Groups("test").Value = "TextCtrls" Then
            Return "TxtNameOfControl.Text"
        Else
            Return "LblNameOfControl.Text"
        End If
    End Function))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. Do you know a solution if the letters are not in the original string? Is it possible? Please don't invest too much time, but maybe you know it....

Comment: @JürgenScheffler If you have access to actual .NET code, yes, it is easy with `MatchEvaluator`.

Comment: nice hint, sure I got .net code available because I am using it via Visual Commander Extension, well I dont have intellisense there but I will find out, thx.